# Python script call pass variable

Tags: python-2.7

im trying to start a python script from within a python script and pass a variable:

```
x = ... # dict
pyExePath = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'python.exe')
subprocess.check_call([pyExePath, os.getcwd() + os.path.sep + 'SubProcess.py'])
```

Is it possible to pass x as argument to the  called script SubProcess.py? I need solution with standard lib (win7 64)

Comment: How large is x? You need to somehow serialize it and unserialize it. It may be too big to be passed as a command-line argument.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) detected. Conventionally, you're not supposed to use `subprocess` to execute `.py` files. You're supposed to `import` them. Is there a particular reason why you're not doing that?

Comment: i need to start the subscript in a new python process

Comment: there is a client server connection in the subscript that i want to abort host side by "killing" the subprocess. the main script runs a loop where this is called. im creating a test

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `multiprocessing` or `threading`.

Comment: i think im just writing the variable to a temp_file and concatenate the subProcess.py with it and then call it...